# Storing Thread and it's state

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a situation, where I receives events on different Threads running on application and for this solution now we are keeping events coming in Threads in Db and later trigger respective action as per the events and letting the Thread terminate after performing few other executions. But Here, I want to store my Thread and it's state somewhere and retrieve events whenever needed from Thread only.
I am novice in Multi-threading and have gone through few links to implement the same by ExecutorServices, etc but nothing seems working.
Is there any way, I can achieve this scenario using Multi-threading?
Or any effort in this context would be a big help for me.

Comment: Can you show us *code*? Something you've been working on. The errors you're getting? We need more information

Comment: What do you mean by saving a thread?

Comment: Maybe try a beginners guide to threading: http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/